# Rails - Conditional :disable_with on submit button for form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancel-button

I have two buttons for my form - a Save changes button and a Cancel button. The Save changes button has the a `disable_with: 'Saving...'` attribute. Because both buttons are submit buttons, the `:disable_with` activates even when the Cancel button is clicked. (The Cancel button code was derived from this link: http://www.keenertech.com/articles/2007/04/10/multiple_form_buttons_in_rails)

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  # form fields
  <%= f.submit "Save changes", :class => 'btn btn-primary', name: 'confirm', disable_with: 'Saving...' %>
  <%= f.submit "Cancel", :class => 'btn', name: 'cancel' %>
<% end %>
```

Any ideas on how I can get a Cancel button that doesn't trigger the `:disable_with` of my Save changes button? I obviously don't want the user to think that the form is saving when they click Cancel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be change 'cancel' button to link with the same css.

Comment: Here's the code I used: `<%= link_to "Cancel", @user, :class => 'btn' %>`. Note: I'm using Twitter Bootstrap for my CSS framework.